# angular 2 losts the styles after extracting component

Tags: javascript, angular, styles

I have the following project structure:

[image]

**`todo-list-item.component.css` content:**

```
.todo-item {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.todo-item .checkbox {
    margin-right: .25em;
}

.todo-item.completed .title {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.todo-item.completed .title,
.todo-item.completed .material-icons {
    color: lightgray;
}

.todo-item input {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.todo-item .actions {
    margin-left: auto;
    /* opacity: 0;*/
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

for example lets reserch last style:

```
.todo-item .actions {
    margin-left: auto;
    /* opacity: 0;*/
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

when I open the page and execute collowing command from console

```
document.querySelector(".todo-item .actions")
```

It returns

```
<div _ngcontent-dny-2="" class="actions">
    <button _ngcontent-dny-2="" class="delete icon">
        <i _ngcontent-dny-2="" class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

But when I open this dom element in tree - I don't see mentioned style:
[image]

Please, explain what wrong I do ?

**P.S.**

Now I have the css file like this:

```
:host {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.checkbox {
    margin-right: .25em;
}

:host(.completed) .title {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

:host(.completed) .title,
:host(.completed) .material-icons {
    color: lightgray;
}

:host input {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

:host .actions {
    margin-left: auto;
    /* opacity: 0;*/
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

But part of styles currently is not binded.

**P.S.**

### solution:

```
:host {
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

:host .checkbox {
    margin-right: .25em;
}

:host-context(.completed) .title {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

:host-context(.completed) .title,
:host-context(.completed) .material-icons {
    color: lightgray;
}

:host input {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

:host .actions {
    margin-left: auto;
    /* opacity: 0;*/
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.todo-item` in your component's css file you should use `:host` to refer to the component itself. If you use `.todo-item`, it is looking for an element with the class attribute of `todo-item` **INSIDE** the component. This is why it doesn't match the component itself. Try changing every instance of `.todo-item` to `:host` in your .css file.

Comment: What do you by *But part of styles currently is not binded.*?

Comment: with :host(). Now I have found soltion